# What is http status code for API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG

Tags: rest-api, http

I am debugging an issue with calling salesforce API and I need to know what is the http response status code for :

> "message":"The REST API is not enabled for this
>   Organization.","errorCode":"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"

500, 405 or what ? For some reasons I cannot try it myself, I have to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG orgs Status code is

> ## **403**

Complete Message:

> [{"message":"The REST API is not enabled for this
>   Organization.","errorCode":"API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG"}],"status":403,"statusText":"Forbidden"}

Comment: @KeithC You revealed the awesome code! :(